# shell - Insert a character at different indexes in a string

Tags: unix, dash-shell

It will eventually be part of a larger script so it needs to be shell scripted. A simple task in other languages, but I'm having trouble accomplishing it in shell. Basically I have a string and I want to insert a "." at all possible indices within the string. The output can be on newlined or separated by spaces. Can anyone help?

Example:
input: "abcd"

output: ".abcd
         a.bcd
         ab.cd
         abc.d
         abcd."

OR

output: ".abcd a.bcd ab.cd abc.d abcd."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple for loop would do:

```
input=abcd
for ((i=0; i<${#input}+1; i++))
do
    echo ${input::$i}.${input:$i}
done
```

This just slices up the string at each index and inserts a `.`.  You can change the `echo` to something else like appending to an array if you want to store them instead ouf output them, of course.

Comment: +1, just a (to the OP possibly irrelevant) side note: for this to work under `ksh` as well you need to explicitly specify the starting index, e.g. `${input:0:$i}`. ksh93's parser barks upon `${foo::$bar}`.

Comment: That for line doesn't seem to work in sh. So I tried the following but the echo line gives a "bad substitution" error.
`max=$((${#input}+1));
for i in 'seq 0 $max';
do;
  echo ${input::$i}.${input:$i};
done;`

*-the ' in the code are actually back ticks `

Comment: After further exploration in the system I'm working on it is actually dash.